# Advantage of scaling vertically and horizontally a function.

Tags: calculus

When one should use vertical scaling and when horizontal? What are the advantages of scaling a function in general and what are the advantages of vertical or horizontal?

Comment: I feel this is a very vague question. It's almost the same question as "What are the advantages of multiplying a number by another number?" - Why is it similar? Because when you scale a function, you multiply it by a number. And this is done very very often.

Comment: If it is done very often then must be a reason.

Comment: @D.Derek If you look at the places where it was done in each case you should see why it was done then. Usually that's to show that some function is really just some well known function in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

The following discussion will help you to find your answer :

A **scale** is a non-rigid translation in that it does alter the shape and size of the graph of the function. A scale will multiply/divide coordinates and this will change the appearance as well as the location. Scaling can apply on most of the functions and translate them to a new graph without loosing the properties of the old graph.

A **vertical scaling** multiplies/divides every $~y-$coordinate by a constant while leaving the $~x-$coordinate unchanged.

A **horizontal scaling** multiplies/divides every $~x-$coordinate by a constant while leaving the $~y-$coordinate unchanged.

The vertical and horizontal scalings can be combined into one expression.